# MacOS Mojave + PHP 7.1.23 + IMAP configuration

Tags: php, homebrew, imap, php-imap

I want to use [imap_append](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php) command in my PHP code. But, when I enabled `extension=php_imap.dll` in the `/etc/php.ini` file on my Mac, I am seeing following warning when I fire any PHP command:

Example:

```
php --version
```

gives output:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_imap.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_imap.dll, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_imap.dll in Unknown on line 0

I have already tried installing following but no use:

```
brew tap kabel/php-ext
brew install php-imap
brew install php@7.1-imap
```

Any clue?

Comment: A dll is a windows dynamic link library, on a mac this would be a .so (Shared Object) library, doesn't look like you have the proper library for the OS.  Take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php

Comment: @SPlatten ok. What exactly I need to do now?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the link I posted.  Also as an alternative you could try wine?  I have wine running on my macOS Mojave and use it to run HeidiSQL and other Windows apps.  works great.

Comment: I’d suggest you to uninstall php and install it again from home brew. Your .ini has windows formats. It will be a better and easy approach